# C++ template - error: expected initializer before '<' token

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to learn about templates, I want my class pair to be able to hold two objects of any type. I just want to provide an accessor function for obj1 now. But I get the following error when I try to complile:

```
error: expected initializer before '<' token
    T1 pair<T1,T2>::getObj1()
```

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

template <class T1, class T2>
class pair
{
  public:
    pair(const T1& t1, const T2& t2) : obj1(t1), obj2(t2){};

    T1 getObj1();

  private:
    T1 obj1;
    T2 obj2;
};

template <class T1, class T2>
T1 pair<T1,T2>::getObj1()
{
    return obj1;
}



int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try removing semicolon after the constructor.

Comment: No that doesnt fix it, thanks though!

Comment: You are clashing  with [std::pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair), try something like `mypair` instead.

Comment: Also you are using namespace std so it may conflict with std::pair.

Comment: It works in Vs2012 with the stray semicolon, provided I call it something else.

Comment: it is not duplicate, it is more generic question about partial specializations in same namespace

Comment: @Sergei is right. I managed to get this error **without** involving `using namespace std`. The question would benefit from an answer that actually addresses what the error means in general, not just pointing out that a totally different question (there is no similarity of the titles) has a solution that fits to this particular example.

Comment: by the way, to unduplicate a question, it need to be edited to describe why the specified duplicate question not helps

Answer (score 16, accepted):

pair is name of a standard class and with the `using namespace std`, there is a collision.

Several solutions :

- Rename your class to something else.
- Dont use the using statement

Comment: Came here to say the exact same thing.

Comment: +1. Yes, **this** is why it's **bad** to use `using namespace std;` (among other reasons, of course)